# Facebook likes sorted in chronological order?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that the facebook API doesn't provide the timestamp of likes when using the likes endpoint

POST /v2.9/{object-id}/likes

But is the response it sorted by time?

Also if I use since and until are they actually going to correctly applied?

From my testing it looks like it is sorted by time and the filters do work, but it would be great to get some confirmation since the documentation doesn't say.

Comment: It would make sense that those are sorted by time; but if the documentation does not explicitly say so, you should probably not rely on it too much (it _could_ change at some point, and if it is not an officially documented feature, I am not sure if that would be announced previously then.) And the endpoint seems to return before/after cursors for pagination only, so I would not rely on since/until working either.

Comment: I wanted to store cursors but then reading [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging) it says you should not store cursors because they can become invalid